# Laravel slowing down over thousand data

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel slowing down over thousand data, if I call the `helper` function in `foreach` loop over thousand data, it slow down and take lot of time to load, I tried chunking the data still same issue.

My `helper` code  is below, if I call the `helper` function in a controller, it takes sometimes 20 minutes to load the data. its really slowing down. The code is very large for the editor so i paste the code in pastebin url below.

https://pastebin.com/zddU83rE

Controller Code Below.

```
<?php
public function cal(Request $request){


$start_date = $request->start_date;
        $end_date = $request->end_date;
        $start_date =\Carbon\Carbon::parse($start_date);  

        $end_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($end_date); 

        $expenses = GeneralHelper::total_expenses(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->start_date), \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->end_date));
        $other_expenses = GeneralHelper::total_savings_interest(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->start_date), \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->end_date));
        $payroll = GeneralHelper::total_payroll(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->start_date), \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->end_date));

        $other_income = GeneralHelper::total_other_income(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->start_date), \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->end_date));
        $interest_paid = GeneralHelper::loans_total_paid_item('interest', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->start_date), \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->end_date));
        $fees_paid = GeneralHelper::loans_total_paid_item('fees', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->start_date), \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->end_date));
        $penalty_paid = GeneralHelper::loans_total_paid_item('penalty', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->start_date), \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->end_date));
        $loan_default = GeneralHelper::loans_total_default(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->start_date), \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->end_date));

        $operating_expenses = $expenses + $payroll;
        $operating_profit = $fees_paid + $interest_paid + $penalty_paid + $other_income;
        $gross_profit = $operating_profit - $operating_expenses - $other_expenses;
        $net_profit = $gross_profit - $loan_default;
        //build graphs here
        $monthly_net_income_data = array();
        $monthly_operating_profit_expenses_data = array();
        $monthly_other_expenses_data = array();
        if (isset($request->end_date)) {
            $date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->end_date);
        } else {
            $date = date("Y-m-d");
        }
        $start_date1 = date_format(date_sub(date_create($date),
            date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 years')),
            'Y-m-d');
        $start_date2 = date_format(date_sub(date_create($date),
            date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 years')),
            'Y-m-d');
        $start_date3 = date_format(date_sub(date_create($date),
            date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 years')),
            'Y-m-d');

        for ($i = 1; $i < 14; $i++) {
            $d = explode('-', $start_date1);
            //get loans in that period
            $o_profit = 0;
            foreach (Loan::where('branch_id', session('branch_id'))->where('year', $d[0])->where('month', $d[1])->where('status',
                'disbursed')->get() as $key) {
                $o_profit = $o_profit + GeneralHelper::loan_paid_item($key->id, 'interest',
                        $key->due_date) + GeneralHelper::loan_paid_item($key->id, 'fees',
                        $key->due_date) + GeneralHelper::loan_paid_item($key->id, 'penalty', $key->due_date);
            }
            $o_profit = round($o_profit + OtherIncome::where('year', $d[0])->where('month',
                    $d[1])->sum('amount'), 2);
            $o_expense = Expense::where('branch_id', session('branch_id'))->where('year', $d[0])->where('month',
                $d[1])->sum('amount');
            foreach (Payroll::where('year', $d[0])->where('month',
                $d[1])->get() as $key) {
                $o_expense = $o_expense + GeneralHelper::single_payroll_total_pay($key->id);
            }
            $o_expense = round($o_expense, 2);
            $ot_expense = 0;
            foreach (Loan::where('branch_id', session('branch_id'))->where('year', $d[0])->where('month', $d[1])->where('status',
                'disbursed')->get() as $key) {
                $ot_expense = $ot_expense + ($key->principal - GeneralHelper::loan_total_paid($key->id));
            }
            $ot_expense = round($ot_expense, 2);
            if ($i == 1 or $i == 13) {
                $ext = ' ' . $d[0];
            } else {
                $ext = '';
            }
            $n_income = round(($o_profit - $o_expense - $ot_expense), 2);
            array_push($monthly_net_income_data, array(
                'month' => date_format(date_create($start_date1),
                    'M' . $ext),
                'amount' => $n_income

            ));
            //add 1 month to start date
            $start_date1 = date_format(date_add(date_create($start_date1),
                date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 months')),
                'Y-m-d');
        }

        for ($i = 1; $i < 14; $i++) {
            $d = explode('-', $start_date2);
            //get loans in that period
            $o_profit = 0;
            foreach (Loan::where('branch_id', session('branch_id'))->where('year', $d[0])->where('month', $d[1])->where('status',
                'disbursed')->get() as $key) {
                $o_profit = $o_profit + GeneralHelper::loan_paid_item($key->id, 'interest',
                        $key->due_date) + GeneralHelper::loan_paid_item($key->id, 'fees',
                        $key->due_date) + GeneralHelper::loan_paid_item($key->id, 'penalty', $key->due_date);
            }
            $o_profit = round($o_profit + OtherIncome::where('branch_id', session('branch_id'))->where('year', $d[0])->where('month',
                    $d[1])->sum('amount'), 2);
            $o_expense = Expense::where('branch_id', session('branch_id'))->where('year', $d[0])->where('month',
                $d[1])->sum('amount');
            foreach (Payroll::where('branch_id', session('branch_id'))->where('year', $d[0])->where('month',
                $d[1])->get() as $key) {
                $o_expense = $o_expense + GeneralHelper::single_payroll_total_pay($key->id);
            }
            $o_expense = round($o_expense, 2);
            $ot_expense = 0;
            foreach (Loan::where('branch_id', session('branch_id'))->where('year', $d[0])->where('month', $d[1])->where('status',
                'disbursed')->get() as $key) {
                $ot_expense = $ot_expense + ($key->principal - GeneralHelper::loan_total_paid($key->id));
            }
            $ot_expense = round($ot_expense, 2);
            if ($i == 1 or $i == 13) {
                $ext = ' ' . $d[0];
            } else {
                $ext = '';
            }
            $n_income = round(($o_profit - $o_expense - $ot_expense), 2);
            array_push($monthly_operating_profit_expenses_data, array(
                'month' => date_format(date_create($start_date2),
                    'M' . $ext),
                'profit' => $o_profit,
                'expenses' => $o_expense

            ));
            //add 1 month to start date
            $start_date2 = date_format(date_add(date_create($start_date2),
                date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 months')),
                'Y-m-d');
        }
        for ($i = 1; $i < 14; $i++) {
            $d = explode('-', $start_date3);
            //get loans in that period
            $o_profit = 0;
            foreach (Loan::where('branch_id', session('branch_id'))->where('year', $d[0])->where('month', $d[1])->where('status',
                'disbursed')->get() as $key) {
                $o_profit = $o_profit + GeneralHelper::loan_paid_item($key->id, 'interest',
                        $key->due_date) + GeneralHelper::loan_paid_item($key->id, 'fees',
                        $key->due_date) + GeneralHelper::loan_paid_item($key->id, 'penalty', $key->due_date);
            }
            $o_profit = round($o_profit + OtherIncome::where('branch_id', session('branch_id'))->where('year', $d[0])->where('month',
                    $d[1])->sum('amount'), 2);
            $o_expense = Expense::where('branch_id', session('branch_id'))->where('year', $d[0])->where('month',
                $d[1])->sum('amount');
            foreach (Payroll::where('branch_id', session('branch_id'))->where('year', $d[0])->where('month',
                $d[1])->get() as $key) {
                $o_expense = $o_expense + GeneralHelper::single_payroll_total_pay($key->id);
            }
            $o_expense = round($o_expense, 2);
            $ot_expense = 0;
            foreach (Loan::where('branch_id', session('branch_id'))->where('year', $d[0])->where('month', $d[1])->where('status',
                'disbursed')->get() as $key) {
                $ot_expense = $ot_expense + ($key->principal - GeneralHelper::loan_total_paid($key->id));
            }
            foreach (SavingTransaction::where('branch_id', session('branch_id'))->where('year', $d[0])->where('month', $d[1])->where('type',
                'interest')->get() as $key) {
                $ot_expense = $ot_expense + $key->amount;
            }
            $ot_expense = round($ot_expense, 2);
            if ($i == 1 or $i == 13) {
                $ext = ' ' . $d[0];
            } else {
                $ext = '';
            }
            $n_income = round(($o_profit - $o_expense - $ot_expense), 2);
            array_push($monthly_other_expenses_data, array(
                'month' => date_format(date_create($start_date3),
                    'M' . $ext),
                'expenses' => $ot_expense

            ));
            //add 1 month to start date
            $start_date3 = date_format(date_add(date_create($start_date3),
                date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 months')),
                'Y-m-d');
        }
        $monthly_net_income_data = json_encode($monthly_net_income_data);
        $monthly_operating_profit_expenses_data = json_encode($monthly_operating_profit_expenses_data);
        $monthly_other_expenses_data = json_encode($monthly_other_expenses_data);
        $start_date = $request->start_date;
        $end_date = $request->end_date;
        return view('report.profit_loss',
            compact('expenses', 'payroll', 'operating_expenses', 'other_income',
                'interest_paid', 'fees_paid', 'penalty_paid', 'operating_profit', 'gross_profit', 'start_date',
                'end_date', 'loan_default', 'net_profit', 'monthly_net_income_data',
                'monthly_operating_profit_expenses_data', 'monthly_other_expenses_data', 'other_expenses'));    
}
```

Comment: Is this ```loan_paid_item``` method called multiple times ?

Comment: The performance issue is likely the result of multiple database calls in your `foreach` loop. Consider [`eager loading`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relationship where possible. You might also want to log to a file some timers within your code to see how long tasks are taking. It might also be worthwhile considering using a [`queue`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#introduction) if this is a long running task.

Comment: @frogeyedman yes its called multiple times

Comment: @devsync could you provide the full code, so the code where this method is called from ? Like pepper said, its likely a issue that has to do with no usage of eager loading.

Comment: @frogeyedman i have updated my question with full code

Answer (score 0):

So there are many things that cause the code to run slow, I will fix some of those from your initial question on the `loan_paid_item` method. This way you can try to implement these techniques on the rest of your code.

keep in mind i did some assumptions about what are relationships and what not, I would suggest following some code convention as this makes it more readable for everyone.

I changed a small thing to the `loan_paid_item` method.

- The first parameter now actually accepts a App\Models\Loan instance, this will allow eager loaded relationships to be passed through.

```php
    //determine paid principal
    public static function loan_paid_item(Loan $loan, $item = 'principal', $date = '')
    {
    }
```

Now I also changed the way you use the `loan_paid_item` method in your controller, see my small example:

- I untroduced local variables to make the code more readable
- for speed; i eager loaded two relationships, now in each forloop this will reduce 3 queries. Since you forloop 14 times this will result in a total of 42 queries.

```php
$loans =  Loan::where('branch_id', session('branch_id'))
->with(['schedules', 'loan_product'])
->where('year', $d[0])
->where('month', $d[1])
->where('status','disbursed')->get();

foreach ($loans as $loan) {
    $interest = GeneralHelper::loan_paid_item($loan, 'interest', $loan->due_date)
    $fees =  GeneralHelper::loan_paid_item($loan, 'fees', $loan->due_date)
    $pentaly GeneralHelper::loan_paid_item($loan, 'penalty', $key->due_date);
    $o_profit = $o_profit + $interest + $fees + $penalty
}
```

Keep in mind that only this wont speed up your code, you need to look at the improvements and add them throughout the controller and helper methods.

Hope this helped you out a bit, also make sure to read these:

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading
- https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices